# Is it possible to use .jsp file in an external directory with Spring MVC (or Boot)?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, tomcat

For example I have a directory called  **/home/user/jsp_pages**
And **main.jsp** file there.
Can I use it in my local Spring MVC project? (Instead of /webapp/WEB-INF/jsp)
We need it because we want to split our work with front-ender.

Answer (score 1):

Its possible basically you will have to modify the application.properties and add your folder location for jsp files

```
spring.view.prefix: /home/user/jsp_pages
spring.view.suffix: .jsp
```

[Here](http://www.leveluplunch.com/java/tutorials/003-getting-started-with-spring-boot/) you can find the full example

Comment: No, it doesn't work. In property **spring.mvc.view.prefix** - we should write relative path to JSP pages.